# SamAccountName to UpperCase

Tags: c#, userprincipal

Does the `SamAccountName` property of `UserPrincipal` not return a string?  I'm trying to take the first character of my `SamAccountName` and convert it `.ToUpperCase()` but `.ToUpperCase()` is not available for `SamAccountName`

```
private void firstCharToUppercase(Prinicpal principal)
{
    UserPrinicpal user = principal as UserPrincipal;
    user.SamAccountName[0].toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly denoted by the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.samaccountname(v=vs.110).aspx), `SamAccountName` returns a string.

However, by using an indexer, you are retrieving the first character as type `char`, not type `string`.

You need to call `ToString()` on the result first.

```
user.SamAccountName[0].ToString().ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the indexer on a `string`, it will return `char` representing the character at that index. The type `char` does have a `ToUpper` method, but it's static. I don't know why the .NET team chose to make `string.ToUpper` non-static and the `char.ToUpper` static.

Try this:

```
private void firstCharToUppercase(Prinicpal principal)
{
    UserPrinicpal user = principal as UserPrincipal;
    char.ToUpper(user.SamAccountName[0]);
}
```

This method is better for making a single character uppercase than calling `ToString()` on the character first. `ToString()` allocates a string which will need to be garbage collected again later, while `char.ToUpper(char)` does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void firstCharToUppercase(Prinicpal principal)
{
    UserPrinicpal user = principal as UserPrincipal;
    user.SamAccountName[0].ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

Try like this

Comment: `.First()` also isn't available but `.ToString().ToUpper();` is so I've added that, thanks!.